# sampler using floating coordinates opencl

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I using OPENCL1.2. I want to access the floating coordinates, but I don't know why the following code gives  CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE

```
  const sampler_t smp = CLK_FILTER_LINEAR | CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;

  float2 cs = (float2)(2 *get_global_id(0), 2*get_global_id(1));
  int2 cs_write = (int2)(2 *get_global_id(0), 2*get_global_id(1));
  float4 a, b, c, d;

  a = read_imagef(in, smp, cs + (float2)( 0.4 ,0.2)); b = read_imagef(in, smp, cs + (float2)(1.4,0.2));
  c = read_imagef(in, smp, cs + (float2)( 0.4 ,1.2)); d = read_imagef(in, smp, cs + (float2)(1.4,1.2));

  /* write the results: */

  write_imagef(out, cs_write + (int2)(0,0), a);
  write_imagef(out, cs_write + (int2)(1,0), b);
  write_imagef(out, cs_write + (int2)(0,1), c);
  write_imagef(out, cs_write + (int2)(1,1), d);
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: What is the build log?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Actually had to use 0.4f or 0.2f. Use f as suffix for all single precision numbers